# Memory usage increases till the app is killed when uploading to Firebase Storage using go-colly

Tags: go, memory-leaks, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a job in Golang that is run every ten minutes that uploads the images from the list of links provided to the Firebase Storage. These links are scraped using a `go-colly` server. The upload is causing memory to bloat and the app is being killed by the server.

The culprit bit of code is given below as removing this function fixes the issue.

```golang
func UploadToStorageFromLink(storage *storage.Client, link string) error {
    cfg := config.ReadConfig()
    bucket, err := storage.Bucket(cfg.BucketName)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    uniqueID := model.UniqueIDForString(link)

    obj := bucket.Object(uniqueID)
    // This is causing the memory bloat.
    writer := obj.NewWriter(context.Background())

    resp, err := http.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(writer, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := writer.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Make the file public for mobile usage.
    if err := obj.ACL().Set(context.Background(), cstorage.AllUsers, cstorage.RoleReader); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

To be precise creating a `NewWriter` is causing issues. Why is new memory being allocated each time I give a new upload job rather than the already allocated memory be used?

I am using the above function within the context of a `go-colly` crawler. This crawler job is invoked using a REST endpoint. And it is invoked every 10 minutes. The crawler has been configured to use `Async` mode with Parallelism limited to 2.

```golang
c := colly.NewCollector(
    colly.AllowedDomains("www.example.com"),
    colly.MaxDepth(1),
)
// Disabling this also works.
c.Async = true
c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
    DomainGlob:  "*",
    Parallelism: 2,
})
```

Running the crawling in non-async mode also fixes the issue with the memory.

What is happening when using async mode that the memory is not freed up during garbage collection between multiple crawl requests? Why is the combination of `Async` of `go-colly` and Firebase Storage upload causing this issue?

Comment: Hi @pepsighan have you checked the size of these images that are being uploaded and how many are being concurrently uploaded? If you could also, edit the question and add any possible logs, would be helpful.

Comment: The file sizes are 600KB-1MB range. I am using go-colly framework to scrape and has been configured with Async mode and Parallelism limited to 2.

Comment: I tried disabling Async on colly and the memory is not exploding on multiple requests. That fixes it but don't know why that worked. Isn't garbage collection to work for the Async mode to free up the memory?

Comment: Hi @pepsighan Seems like there could be memory leaks issue when using async, it works recursively and can't control memory. Maybe you could try to use a queue as explained here: https://github.com/gocolly/colly/issues/329

Comment: I also used queue afterwards, while it may have helped a bit; the source of the problem was some place else.